# Get a specific column number by column name using awk

Tags: unix, awk

i have n number of file, in these files a specific column named "thrudate" is given at different column number in every files.

i Just want to extract the value of this column from all files in one go. So i tried with using awk. Here i'm considering only one file, and extracting the values of thrudate

```
awk -F, -v header=1,head="" '{for(j=1;j<=2;j++){if($header==1){for(i=1;i<=$NF;i++){if($i=="thrudate"){$head=$i;$header=0;break}}} elif($header==0){print $0}}}' file | head -10
```

How i have approached:

- used find command to find all the similar files and then executing the second step for every file
- loop all fields in first row, checking the column name with header values as 1 (initialized it to 1 to check first row only), once it matched with 'thrudate', i set header as 0, then break from this loop.
- once i get the column number then print it for every row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following awk script:

*print_col.awk*:

```
# Find the column number in the first line of a file 
FNR==1{
    for(n=1;n<=NF;n++) {
        if($n == header) {
            next
        }
    }
}

# Print that column on all other lines
{
    print $n
}
```

Then use `find` to execute this script on every file:

```
find ... -exec awk -v header="foo" -f print_col.awk {} +
```

---

In comments you've asked for a version that could print multiple columns based on their header names. You may use the following script for that:

*print_cols.awk*:

```
BEGIN {
    # Parse headers into an assoc array h
    split(header, a, ",")
    for(i in a) {
        h[a[i]]=1
    }   
}

# Find the column numbers in the first line of a file
FNR==1{
    split("", cols) # This will re-init cols
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if($i in h) {
            cols[i]=1
        }
    }   
    next
}

# Print those columns on all other lines
{
    res = ""
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if(i in cols) {
            s = res ? OFS : ""
            res = res "" s "" $i
        }
    }   
    if (res) {
        print res 
    }   
}
```

Call it like this:

```
find ... -exec awk -v header="foo,bar,test" -f print_cols.awk {} +
```

Comment: thank you, this is damn correct, just wanted to know if we can do this to fetch 2 columns?

Comment: I've added that.