# sed/Awk/cut... How to decide which to use to parse Docker output?

Tags: bash, docker, awk, sed, sh

My output:

```
docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
jenkins/jenkins     lts                 806f56c84444        8 days ago          703MB
mongo               latest              0da05d84b1fe        2 weeks ago         394MB
```

I would like to just cut the image ID alone from the output.

I tried using `cut`:

```
docker images | cut -d " " -f1
REPOSITORY
jenkins/jenkins
```

The `-f1` just gives me the repository names, if I use `-f3` it tends to be empty. Since the delimiter is not a single space I don't see how to get the desired output.

Can we `cut` based on field names?

I read the documentation and did not see anything relevant. I also saw that there is a way to achieve this using sed/AWK which i'm still figuring out.

In the meanwhile is there a easier way to achieve this using the `cut` command?

I'm new to Unix/Linux, how can I determine which of Sed/AWK/Cut to prefer?

Comment: `docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)`

Comment: The `docker` command comes with a `--format` option to let you extract exactly the fields you need in a format suitable for your purposes. (Admittedly, the use of Go format strings isn't immediately obvious to us non-Go people.)

Comment: With tripleee's hint: `docker images --format "{{.ID}}"`

Comment: And no, `cut` doesn't support extracting fields by name, though this isn't hard to do in Awk, either. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45608145/get-a-specific-column-number-by-column-name-using-awk

Comment: I thinking about casting a close vote: "which is the best" questions are typically based on opinion, and are not a good fit for this Q&A.

Comment: Are those fixed width fields or tab-separated columns or columns separated by multiple blank chars or what in your posted sample input?

Comment: Like most tools which format columnar output for the screen, `docker` uses the equivalent of `printf`` space padding. As mentioned in my answer, the dimensions of the columns depend on your screen size, so while the oolumns are fixed width, the widths cannot always be predicted, or you have to use tricks like lying about your screen dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

Your input seems to have a fixed width of 20 chars for each field, so you can make use of gawk's `FIELDWIDTHS` feature.

```
$ awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="20 20 20 20 20" '{ print $3 }' file
IMAGE ID
806f56c84444
0da05d84b1fe
$
$ awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="20 20 20 20 20" '{ printf "%20s%20s\n", $1, $3 }' file
REPOSITORY          IMAGE ID
jenkins/jenkins     806f56c84444
mongo               0da05d84b1fe
```

From `man gawk`:

> If the FIELDWIDTHS variable is set to a space-separated list of numbers, each field is expected to have fixed width, and gawk splits up the record using the specified widths.  Each field width may optionally be preceded by a colon-separated value specifying the number of characters to skip before the field starts.  The value of FS is ignored.  Assigning a new value to FS or FPAT overrides the use of FIELDWIDTHS.

Answer (score 2):

You have to "squeeze" the space padding in the default output to single space.

`1  2` == `1-space-space-2` == Field 1 before 1st space, Field between 1st and 2nd space, Field 3 after 2nd space.

`cut -d' ' -f1` ==> '1'

`cut -d' ' -f2` ==> ''  empty field between 1st and 2nd delimiter

`cut -d' ' -f3` ==> '2'

So, in your case use `sed` to replace consecutive spaces with 1:

`docker images | sed 's/  */ /g' | cut -d " " -f1,3`

If the output is fixed columns widths, then you can use this variant of cut:

`docker images | cut -c1-20,41-60`

This will cut out columns 41 to 60, where we find the Image ID.

If ever the output uses `TAB` for padding, you should use `expand -t n` to make the output consistently space padded then apply the appropriate `cut -cx,y`, e.g. (numbers may need adjusting):

`docker images | expand -t 4 | cut -c1-20,41-60`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
docker images | tr -s ' ' | cut -f3 -d' '
```

The command `tr -s ' '` convert multiple spaces into a single one and after with cut you can grab your field. This work fine if values in your field haven't spaces.

Comment: Nope. Does'nt work. 

docker images | cut -f1,2,4 -d$'\t'
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
jenkins/jenkins     lts                 806f56c84444        9 days ago          703MB
mongo               latest              0da05d84b1fe        2 weeks ago         394MB

Comment: docker images | tr -s ' ' | cut -f3 -d " " 
This worked Perfectly

Answer (score 0):

With `Procedural Text Edit` it's :

```
forEach line {
    if (contains ci "REPOSITORY") { remove }
    keepRange word 2 1
}
removeEmptyLines // <- optional
```

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, avoid parsing output meant for human consumption. Many modern utilities offer an option to produce output in some standard format like JSON or XML, or even CSV (though that is less strictly specified, and exists in multiple "dialects").

`docker` in particular has a generalized [`--format` option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#format-the-output) which allows you to specify your own output format:

```
docker images --format "{{.ID}}"
```

If you cannot avoid writing your own parser (are you really sure!? Look again!), `cut` is suitable for output with a specific single-character delimiter, or otherwise fairly regular output. For everything else, I would go with Awk. Out of the box, it parses columns from *sequences of* whitespace, so it does precisely what you specifically ask for:

```
docker images | awk 'NR>1 { print $3 }'
```

(`NR>1` skips the first line, which contains the column headers.)

In the case of fixed-width columns, it allows you to pull out a string by index:

```
docker images | awk 'NR>1 { print substr($0, 41, 12) }'
```

... though you could do that with `cut`, too:

```
docker images | cut -c41-53
```

... but notice that Docker might adjust column widths depending on your screen size!

Awk lets you write regular expression extractions, too:

```
awk 'NR>1 { sub(/^([^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]+){2}/, ""); sub(/[[:space]].*/, ""); print }'
```

This is where it overlaps with `sed`:

```
sed -n '2,$s/^[^ ]\+[ ]\+[^ ]\+[ ]\+\([^ ]\+\)[ ].*/\1/p'
```

though `sed` is significantly less human-readable, especially for nontrivial scripts. (This is still pretty trivial.)

If you haven't used regex before, the above will seem cryptic, but it really isn't very hard to pick apart. We are looking for sequences of non-spaces (a field in a column) followed by sequences of spaces (a column separator) - two before the ID field and whatever comes after it, starting from the first space after the ID column.

If you want to learn shell scripting, you should probably also learn at least the basics of Awk (and a passing familiarity with `sed`). If you just want to get the job done, and perhaps aren't specifically interested in learning U*x tools (though you probably should be anyway!), perhaps instead learn a modern scripting language like Python or Ruby.

... Here's a [Python `docker` library](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
for image in client.images.list():
    print(image.id)
```

Comment: But really, just say no to spending your life writing ad-hoc parsers for poorly-specified formats with never-ending corner cases. I am living proof: that way lies madness.

Answer (score 0):

*Can we `cut` based on field names*? No.

*How can I determine which of Sed/AWK/Cut to prefer*? YMMV. For this particular input where fields are separated by two or more spaces, using awk you could set field separator to `"  +"` (two or more spaces), look for desired field name (`IMAGE ID` below) and print only that particular field:

```
$ awk -F"  +" '                     # set field separator
{
    if(f=="")                       # while we have not determined the desired field
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)          # ... keep looking
            if($i=="IMAGE ID")
                f=i
    if(f!="")                       # once found
        print $f                    # start printing it
}' file
```

Output:

```
IMAGE ID
806f56c84444
0da05d84b1fe
```

As one-liner:

```
$ awk -F"  +" '{if(f=="")for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="IMAGE ID")f=i;if(f!="")print $f}' file
```